# Should ruby rspec test be inside the module?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Let's say I'm writing a ruby program with a class inside a module. Should the rspec tests be inside the module or outside?

Here is an example of the test's outside the module:

```rb
# file: lib/calculator.rb
module Computation
  class Calculator
    def add(x,y)
      return x+y
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# file: spec/calculator_spec.rb
require_relative '../lib/calculator'

RSpec.describe Computation::Calculator do
  it 'should add two numbers' do
    calc = Computation::Calculator.new
    expect(calc.add(1,2)).to eql(3)
  end
end
```

Here is what it would like if the test was inside the module.

```rb
# file: spec/calculator_spec.rb
require_relative '../lib/calculator'

module Computation
  RSpec.describe Calculator do
    it 'should add two numbers' do
      calc = Calculator.new
      expect(calc.add(1, 2)).to eql(3)
    end
  end
end
```

Which one would be better? Is there a community convention? Does it matter?

Comment: RSpec itself uses all kind of variants: [`RSpec.describe 'RSpec::Core::Set'`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/spec/rspec/core/set_spec.rb), [`RSpec.describe RSpec::Core::Example`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/spec/rspec/core/example_spec.rb), [`module RSpec ; module Core ; RSpec.describe Metadata`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/spec/rspec/core/metadata_spec.rb), [`module RSpec::Core ; RSpec.describe BacktraceFormatter`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/main/spec/rspec/core/backtrace_formatter_spec.rb) and others, all within one test suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version `RSpec.describe Computation::Calculator do` is the way to go. I have never seen a project using the second version.